# Volume form of manifold with metric $ds^2=\frac{dx^2}{x^2}+\frac{dy^2}{y^2}$

Tags: riemannian-geometry, differential-forms, volume

How do you write $ds^2=\frac{dx^2}{x^2}+\frac{dy^2}{y^2}$ in matrix form? Is it $\frac{1}{x^2}$ and $\frac{1}{y^2}$ on the diagonal and $0$ else-where? I need this to calculate the volume form.
$g=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ is the matrix representation of $g=ds^2=dx^2+dy^2$
so for $ds^2=\frac{dx^2}{x^2}+\frac{dy^2}{y^2}$ my best guess at the matrix representation is $\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{x^2} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{y^2} \end{bmatrix}.$

This is needed to calculate the volume form, which has the formula, $\omega=\sqrt{|g|}dx^1 \wedge dx^2\cdot\cdot\cdot dx^n.$

So I think the answer is $\omega=\frac{dx}{x}$ for my case. Correct?

Does that mean I should write integrals like $\int f(x)\frac{dx}{x}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your expression for the metric, being $g=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{x^2} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{y^2} \end{bmatrix}$ is correct, as $ds^2=\sum_{i}\sum_{j}{g_{ij}\ dx^idx^j}$.

But i thing your expression for $\omega$ is incorrect, as $|g|=\frac{1}{x^2y^2}$, so
$$\omega=\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2y^2}}dxdy={\frac{1}{xy}}dxdy$$
which is the volume element for this 2D space.

Comment: I think you forgot the square root in the expression of the volume form

Comment: @Didier thank you

Comment: So if I integrate under a curve f(x) I would just have the form $\frac{dx}{x}$ right?

Comment: i think if you want to find the area between $y=0$ and $y=f(x)$ then you calculate $\int_{x_0}^{x_1} \int_0^{f(x)}   {\frac{1}{xy}}dxdy$, but i haven't looked closely at this bit before